# Can still see advertisements

Tags: discussion, advertising

My sincere apologies if this is not the right place to ask this question.

My [understanding](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges) regarding advertisements is

> Ads automatically reduce for a SO user when he or she reaches 200 reputation points. This of course is not applicable to the **bar to the right**.

Fair enough... However I never expected that it was also applicable to the bar on Top?

For example

[image]

One may say that it is a sponsored link. But for me it is still an advertisement.

Am I missing something? If yes, can someone point me to a link which explains which bars/area will always show advertisements irrespective of reputation.

Comment: You are looking at a tag page, not a question page. The sponsored message for tags is not exempt.

Comment: Note the wording: "Some ads are now automatically disabled". Not all, some. Nothing wrong with that.

Comment: @ShadowWizard: Yup nothing wrong with that :) Please read the last line of the question. I was looking for an authoritative link which explained it which MIH and Josh Caswell already pointed me out. :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Ads automatically **reduce** for a SO user when he or she reaches 200 reputation points

They never said it will be hidden ;)

Anyway, the ads that hide are "leaderboard" ads in question pages, clearly demonstrated [in the help page](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/reduced-ads).

[image]

Comment: Sorry but this doesn't answer my question. Please see the last line in the question.

Comment: Thanks for the edit. It now does answer my question :)

Comment: @SiddharthRout at first glance I thought the last line was a part of the pasted photo.. sorry :) I updated the answer...

Comment: + 1 I need 8 mins before I can accept this answer :)

Answer (score 5):

The advertisements that go away are those like the one here:

[image]

The sponsored links for a tag aren't the kind of ads that get hidden by that privilege. They'll always be there.

Comment: Thanks for replyiing. However, Sorry but this doesn't answer my question. Please see the last line in the question.

Comment: Well, it does answer that @SiddharthRout. Yes, you're missing something. And you can find that information (which is correct) in the answer above.

Comment: The page for the privilege -- http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/reduced-ads -- explains the details, @SiddharthRout.

Comment: @Bart: It doesn't answer this part ` If yes, can someone point me to a link which explains which bars/area will always show advertisements irrespective of reputation.`

Comment: @JoshCaswell: Put that as an answer :)